# Does anyone know what is complex collections in azure Search service?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

From Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity), it says these:

1. Maximum complex collection fields: 40 Maximum elements across all
2. complex collections per document:3000

But what is complex collection? If I have a collection of string, is it a complex collection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In terms of JSON, a complex collection is an array of objects. In terms of an index definition in Azure Cognitive Search, it’s a field of type `Collection(Edm.ComplexType)`. The subfields of such a field correspond to the JSON properties of objects in an array.

For example, if you define a field Addresses with string subfields Street and City, then in the context of a document it might look like this:

```
{
  ...
  "Addresses": [
    { "Street": "123 Main Street", "City": "Bellevue" },
    { "Street": "221B Baker Street", "City": "London" }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I see. So my string collection is safe then.

Comment: Yes. There is no limit on the number of elements in other collection types.